# BMI calculator using classes

Tags: java

I can't figure out what to put as I'm required to create the calculator with classes. Any help would be appreciated.

```
    import java.util.*;
public class BMI
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        heightInInches();
        weightInPounds();
        outputBMI();

    }
    public static void heightInInches()
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("What is your height in feet between 2 and 7? " );
        int feet = input.nextInt();

        while (feet < 2 || feet > 7)
        {
          System.out.print("Retry between 2 and 7: ");
          feet = input.nextInt();
        }

        System.out.println("How many inches between 0 and 11? " );
        int inches = input.nextInt();

        while (inches < 0 || inches > 11)
        {
          System.out.print("Retry between 0 and 11: ");
          inches = input.nextInt();

        }
        int actualHeight = (feet * 12) + inches;

        System.out.println("You are this tall in inches: " + actualHeight); 
    }
    public static int weightInPounds()
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("What is your weight in stone between 3 and 30? " );
        int stone = input.nextInt();

        while (stone < 3 || stone > 30)
        {
          System.out.print("Retry between 3 and 30: ");
          stone = input.nextInt();
        }

        System.out.println("How many pounds between 0 and 13? " );
        int pounds = input.nextInt();

        while (pounds < 0 || pounds > 13)
        {
          System.out.print("Retry between 0 and 13: ");
          pounds = input.nextInt();
        }
        int actualWeight =(stone * 14) + pounds;
        System.out.println("You are this heavy in pounds: " + actualWeight); 
        return actualWeight;

    }
    public static void outputBMI(int heightInInches, int weightInPounds)
    {
        double BMI = (weightInPounds * 703) / (heightInInches * heightInInches);

        System.out.println("This is your BMI: " + BMI);

    }
}
```

It's where it says outputBMI(); I'm not quite sure what I'm supposed to put in these brackets as there's nothing I can put in there without it throwing an error at me.

Comment: You are using variables that don't exist.

Comment: Your problem description is extremely unclear. One really obvious problem: outputBMI takes two parameters `int heightInInches, int weightInPounds` but you call it with none: `outputBMI();`

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how I call it with parameters as everything I've typed isn't working? cheers for the help!

Comment: Inside `main` you call it like this `outputBMI(8, 200);` you can use this codepad to start going https://codepad.remoteinterview.io/PISVGARCRS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were not passing any parameters to the **outputBMI** method.

Also consider using [Double](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html)'s instead of [Integers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html)'s throughout so you can ask less questions :)

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int height = heightInInches();
        int weight = weightInPounds();
        outputBMI(height, weight);

    }

    public static int heightInInches()
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("What is your height in feet between 2 and 7? " );

        int feet = input.nextInt();

        while (feet < 2 || feet > 7)
        {
          System.out.print("Retry between 2 and 7: ");
          feet = input.nextInt();
        }

        System.out.println("How many inches between 0 and 11? " );
        int inches = input.nextInt();

        while (inches < 0 || inches > 11)
        {
          System.out.print("Retry between 0 and 11: ");
          inches = input.nextInt();

        }

        int actualHeight = (feet * 12) + inches;
        System.out.println("You are this tall in inches: " + actualHeight); 
        return actualHeight;
    }

    public static int weightInPounds()
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("What is your weight in stone between 3 and 30? " );
        int stone = input.nextInt();

        while (stone < 3 || stone > 30)
        {
          System.out.print("Retry between 3 and 30: ");
          stone = input.nextInt();
        }

        System.out.println("How many pounds between 0 and 13? " );
        int pounds = input.nextInt();

        while (pounds < 0 || pounds > 13)
        {
          System.out.print("Retry between 0 and 13: ");
          pounds = input.nextInt();
        }
        int actualWeight =(stone * 14) + pounds;
        System.out.println("You are this heavy in pounds: " + actualWeight); 
        return actualWeight;

    }

    public static void outputBMI(int heightInInches, int weightInPounds)
    {
        double BMI = (weightInPounds * 703) / (heightInInches * heightInInches);

        System.out.println("This is your BMI: " + BMI);
    }
}
```

Try it here: https://repl.it/E5fv/0

Answer (score 0):

In an object oriented way. It would make sense to create three classes Weight, Height, and BMI. See below. This approach encapsulates the various conversion to the inches and pounds to BMI formula.

```
import java.util.*;

class Weight {
  static private int STONE_TO_POUNDS = 14;
  private Integer weightInPounds;

  void setWeight(int stone, int pounds) {
    weightInPounds = (stone * STONE_TO_POUNDS) + pounds;
  }

  Integer getWeightInPounds() {
    return weightInPounds;
  }
}

class Height {
   static private int FEET_TO_INCHES = 12;
   private Integer heightInInches;

  void setHeight(int feet, int inches) {
      heightInInches = (feet * FEET_TO_INCHES) + inches;
   }

  Integer getHeightAsInches() {
    return heightInInches;

  }
}

class BMI {
  private Height height;
  private Weight weight;

  void setHeight(Height height) {
     this.height = height;
  }

  void setWeight(Weight weight) {
    this.weight = weight;
  }

  double calculate() {
      return (weight.getWeightInPounds() * 703) / (height.getHeightAsInches().intValue() * height.getHeightAsInches().intValue());
  }
}


public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        BMI bmi = new BMI();


        bmi.setHeight(getHeight());
        bmi.setWeight(getWeight());

        outputBMI(bmi);

    }

    public static Height getHeight()
    {
        Height height = new Height();
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("What is your height in feet between 2 and 7? " );

        int feet = input.nextInt();

        while (feet < 2 || feet > 7)
        {
          System.out.print("Retry between 2 and 7: ");
          feet = input.nextInt();
        }

        System.out.println("How many inches between 0 and 11? " );
        int inches = input.nextInt();

        while (inches < 0 || inches > 11)
        {
          System.out.print("Retry between 0 and 11: ");
          inches = input.nextInt();

        }

        height.setHeight(feet, inches);
        System.out.println("You are this tall in inches: " + height.getHeightAsInches()); 

        return height;
    }

    public static Weight getWeight()
    {
        Weight weight = new Weight();
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("What is your weight in stone between 3 and 30? " );
        int stone = input.nextInt();

        while (stone < 3 || stone > 30)
        {
          System.out.print("Retry between 3 and 30: ");
          stone = input.nextInt();
        }

        System.out.println("How many pounds between 0 and 13? " );
        int pounds = input.nextInt();

        while (pounds < 0 || pounds > 13)
        {
          System.out.print("Retry between 0 and 13: ");
          pounds = input.nextInt();
        }


        weight.setWeight(stone, pounds);
        System.out.println("You are this heavy in pounds: " + weight.getWeightInPounds()); 
        return weight;

    }

    public static void outputBMI(BMI bmi)
    {

        System.out.println("This is your BMI: " + bmi.calculate());
    }
}
```